# NullPointer in Arraylist java

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I tried to create two dimensional `ArrayList` i get `NullPointerException` in 7 line

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] g = new ArrayList[500];
    for(int i = 1;i < HEIGHT - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 1;j < WIDTH - 1; j++){
            if(MAP[i][j] == 0){
                int cur = i * HEIGHT + j;
                if(MAP[i+1][j] == 0){
                    g[cur].add(cur + HEIGHT);
                }
                if(MAP[i-1][j] == 0){
                    g[cur].add(cur - HEIGHT);
                }
                if(MAP[i][j+1] == 0){
                    g[cur].add(cur + 1);
                }
                if(MAP[i][j-1] == 0){
                    g[cur].add(cur - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's an empty array with 500 null pointers that could point to array lists, but you need to assign arraylists to each of the 500 first (in a for-loop, presumably)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use your debugger, you should be able to see that this doesn't create an `ArrayList` only an array of references to them which are all `null`

What you intended was

```
List<Integer>[] g = new ArrayList[500];
for (int i = 0; i < g.length; i++)
    g[i] = new ArrayList<>();
```